# Name for PID control with acceleration term?

Tags: space-shuttle, attitude-determination-and-control

The space shuttle TVC controller used a PID control scheme with an acceleration term for load management at high dynamic pressures. The acceleration term would be ramped up at 547 ft/s (before max Q) and ramped down at Mach 2.2. The purpose was to allow the shuttle to deviate from its pitch schedule and out of its target orbital plane in order to keep wind shear and other loads below a max threshold.

Is there a standard name for this type of control scheme? PID means Proportional-Integral-Derivative, but here I have also an acceleration term. How should I refer to the acceleration gain if Proportional = P, Integral = I, and Derivative = D?

Comment: "modified PID"?

Comment: That purely depends on your controlled variable PID controlling velocity is exactly that, P = velocity, I = distance, D = acceleration. In case of engine controls, the controller will control trust, which is directly proportional to acceleration; P=thrust/acceleration, I=velocity, D=jerk In case of controlling position/trajectory, such controller would likely deviate from standard by using a second-integral term.

Comment: So the TVC (thrust-vectoring control) system corrects for attitude errors, and P = attitude gain, I = "auto-trim" integrator gain, and D = attitude rate gain. The acceleration term factors in the angular acceleration and the lateral translational acceleration of the rocket. Throttle control is separate from TVC and I'm not considering that here, although I know the space shuttle used a PI (no D, maybe to eliminate damping from that term and make the controller more responsive?). Anyway, it's the acceleration term in the TVC that I'm hoping to make sense of :)

Comment: By the way, the throttle controller just holds constant throttle until you hit max Q, at which point it just follows a simple lookup table (the "throttle bucket") of throttle vs. velocity. No feedback involved, and no error signal involved either---until you hit 3g, at which point the 3g PI controller takes over to track the 3g acceleration line. That controller uses the acceleration difference from 3g as its error signal, but here the acceleration is the proportional (P) term---unlike the TVC, where attitude is P, attitude rate is D, and acceleration is ?